# What is the derivative of velocity with respect to height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I have a question on fluid dynamics which requires to find the derivative of velocity wrt to height? It was solved by my teacher but I am not able to grasp the solution.

Here is the question: -
A tank is filled with water upto a height h. The top of the tank has an area of cross section A. Water is coming out through a circular hole of area A/3. Find the initial acceleration with which the top level of water is decreasing?

[image]The solution given:-

Can someone explain the part where derivative is taken and velocity changes into acceleration.

Comment: The problem is the tank cross section in the question you have given is H. Is the H equal to a? If the H is equal to a then continuity equation is right otherwise there should be H in the continuity. There should be some relation between the pipe cross section area (a) and the tank cross section area (H)

Comment: Sorry that will be A. Lemme edit the question.

Comment: So the v1 *(dv1/dt) is indeed acceleration write v1=dh/dt and simplify to end up dv1^2/dt^2 as acceleration.

Comment: Please post questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than posting pictures of notes.

Comment: My question was to understand how h disappeared from the rhs and dv/dh apperaed on lhs. But I did not find any convincing answer.

Answer (score 1):

$a=dv/dt$

$a=(dv/dh)\times( dh/dt)$  (Multiply and divide by dh or to say using chain rule)

$a=v(dv/dh)$

Comment: "multiply and divide by $\mathrm{d}h$" really means using the chain rule

Comment: @NiharKarve Yes.....

Comment: I know that fact but I did not understand the point where both sides are differentiated w.r.t to h and after that how the peculiar equation in the second pic came.

Comment: @AdityaKumar It's not differentiating w.r.t h , it is using chain rule. Replace dh/dt=v (in the second equation)

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could dolve the question from scratch.

Comment: @AdityaKumar your question wasn't about solving the question but why there is a gradient of v, that question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

v1=dh/dt,
Hence, v1*(dv1/dh) =(dh/dt) *(dv1/dh)
=dv1/dt
=d^2(h)/dt^2=acceleration,
This is how we end up with acceleration term a.